# Constrains on class name for hibernate query in java

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, hibernate, mapping

Sorry if it is a stupid question but I don't know Java almost at all.
I have a table "Orders" in a postgreSQL database, which I access by Hibernate, mapping the table to a class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Orders")
public class Orders { ... }
```

This works. However, if I change the class name to "Order", thus:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Orders")
public class Order { ... }
```

I get an error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Orders is not mapped [from Orders]
```

of course I have already updated the hibernate xml config file, switching from

```
<mapping class="<path>.orders.Orders"/>
```

to

```
<mapping class="<path>.orders.Order"/>
```

any idea why ? What am I missing ? The mapping between the DB table and the class is established only on the basis of the @table annotation and not on the class name, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the fact that JPQL is not SQL. It works on entity names and property/field names, not on table names and column names. Since you changes the name of the entity class from `Orders` to `Order`, you need to change your JPQL queries from

```
select o from Orders o ...
```

to

```
select o from Order o ...
```

The name of the table that the entity maps is completely irrelevant.